# Failed to set value with application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying a very simple code to inject a value from application.properties.
The value which is setted is the property name.

What's wrong with the code?

application.properties

```
set.browser = ie
```

```java
    public class A {

        @Value("${set.browser}")
        private String browser;

        public A(){}

        public void print(){
            System.out.println(browser);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public class ABean {
        @Bean
        public A getA(){
            return new A();
        }
    }

    public class AMain {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(A.class);

            A a = context.getBean(A.class);
            a.print();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You never start any Spring Boot aplication, which would read the properties. Annotate AMain with SpringBootApplcation, and replace the first line of the main method by `ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(AMain.class, args);`

Comment: @michalk that's not the problem: the method is a `@Bean`-annotated method of a configuration class, so it does create a Spring bean, that Spring will inject.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, That's solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your application is not spring boot application - you've just instanted spring context even without component scan. Secondly beacause of lack of component scan, your ABean is never created - your context has only A bean. To fix this you can create context from ABean:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ABean.class);
```

Thirdly you didn't configured PropertySource (if your application was spring boot application, application.properties would be default property source and it wouldn't be needed):

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
@Configuration
class ABean {
  @Bean
  public A getA() {
    return new A();
  }

}
```